# How to do the shortcut `ALT+/` on a German keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-docs

I see more and more webapps (such as Google Docs) using the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to access the search mode.

You find it in Google Docs, for instance, when you collapse the top menu bar, then on the very left this shows up:

> Search the menus (ALT+/)

The problem is that the German keyboard layout has the `/` above the `7` and you reach it only with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>.

[image: German keyboard layout small]

[Image Source Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout#/media/File:KB_Germany.svg)

Therefore I have tried the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> but it does not work.

I also tried the `/` key on the NumPad, which allows a direct <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> combination as required, but it does not work either.

So the big question is: How to do the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> shortcut this way that it works?

Comment: Can you try Alt + whatever key is in the same location (left of rshift) as the / key is in US layout?

Comment: I have tried, but it does not work. I actually tried all key combinations with ALT + sign/letter. Nothing.

Comment: Damn it, I don't know why, **but now the ALT + Numpad-Slash works!** in Google Docs and Google Spreadsheet.